# How does a Perl script know if it's running in the debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I have a script that redirects STDIN/STDOUT to a file normally.  But, debugging is a lot more efficient if it doesn't do that.  Is there a $DB:xxx variable or something that lets the script know so it can behave differently?

Comment: Do you mean the interactive debugger or Perl's debugging functionality? (see comments on answers below)

Comment: This was for running perl -d, shich I believe is Perl's debugging functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find any way of determining if they debugger is running directly, but you could check if well-known debugger variable `$DB::single` exists using the following:

```perl
if ( $DB::{ single } ) {
   say "Debugger is running";
}
```

Another approach would be to check if the debugger module is loaded.

```perl
if ( $INC{ "perl5db.pl" } ) {
   say "Debugger is running";
}
```

Finally, the debugger requires that Perl is running in debug support mode, and `$^P` indicates whether Perl is in this mode or not.

```perl
if ( $^P ) {
   say "Perl is in debug support mode";
}
```

The debugger isn't the only tool that requires putting Perl in debug support mode. Others include Devel::NYTProf, Devel::Cover, Devel::Trace, and more. So this approach can't be used to specifically check if the debugger is running. But it might be what you actually want.

Comment: Kudos to Eugen Konkov for bringing up `$^P`.

Comment: (However, his answer incorrectly describes what it does.)

Comment: I just pasted documentation as is.

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, Please consult the documentation for `$^P` (in perlvar) and `-d` (in perlrun).

Comment: Please notice that `$DB::single` is false when we step over the function. Did you mean `if( exists $DB::{ single })`? You mention that in the description, but forgot in the code.

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, `$DB::{ single }` isn't the same as `$DB::single`. It's the same as `*DB::single`, except that it doesn't vivify the symbol (which would render the test useless).

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the perl source code of DB.pm (`perldoc -m DB`), I noticed that `$SIG{INT}` is globally set at the end.

This seems to work, at least for a trivial program:

```
if (\&DB::catch && $SIG{'INT'} && $SIG{'INT'} == \&DB::catch) {
    say "Debugging ?"
}
```

If it's not applicable, I guess it's possible to subclass DB.pm and create a simple debugger which overrides `cont` and does extra bookkeeping.

Answer (score 1):

To find that your script is under debugger you need to check: `$^P` variable:

```
if ( $^P ) {
    # running under a debugger
}
```

https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug#Calling-the-Debugger

If you script was run without `-d` option then `$DB::single` does noting.

According to [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts#Writing-Your-Own-Debugger) the minimal debugger is `sub DB::DB {}`.
So another method to check that your script is under debugger is:

```perl
if( defined &DB::DB ){
   # running under a debugger
}
```

Comment: Not quite. `$^P` indicates whether Perl is running in debug support mode or not, not whether the debugger is running or not. This is not quite the same. For example, `$^P` will be true when using Devel::Trace (`perl -d:Trace ...`) even though the debugger isn't running. And `$DB::single` won't do anything then either, since the debugger is not running. But, it could be what the OP actually wants, so +1.

Comment: @ikegami: Then I completely do not understand documentation. It says `running under the debugger`. It seems this sections requires more description. Also `perlrun` said that `-d:MOD runs the program under the control of a debugging`. I believe, it is not possible that `$DB::single` won't do anything, when `-d` is used ( debugger `Perl_init_debugger(aTHX)` is initialized). [perldebguts](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts). Please correct me, If I am wrong.

Comment: @ikegami: `Devel::Trace` just do not bring interactive debugging, but that does not meant it does not make use of `$DB::single` and not under debugger.

Comment: Re "*It says running under the debugger.*", That is not accurate. It is running with debuggin support, as the documentation for $^P (in perlvar) says. ///  Re "*perlrun said that -d:MOD runs the program under the control of a debugging" module*, This one is correct. Like it says `-d:Trace` puts Devel::Trace "in control". Devel::Trace is not the debugger. `-d` without a module puts the debugger "in control".

Comment: Re "*that does not meant it does not make use of $DB::single and not under debugger.*", True, yet it's not under the debugger, and it doesn't create and use $DB::single like the debugger does.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks. Now that is much clear. `-d` turns on Perl's debugging functionality (eg. Perl_init_debugger( aTHX ) is called ). After that Perl inserts value of `PERL5DB` environment variable as first line (The line with number zero) of a script. By default it is `BEGIN{ require "perl5db.pl" }`. Which brings the **interactive debugging**. In case of `-d:MOD` the `use Devel::MOD` will be used as the first line and, I assume, `PERL5DB` will be ignored. Still `-d:MOD` runs script under debugger, but depending on MOD implementation it could be without **the interactive debugging**.

Comment: @ikegami: *RE: True, yet it's not under the debugger*. I think we need to clarify a bit. There are two debuggers: 1. Perl's debugger functionality and 2. the interactive debugging implemented by `perl5db.pl` or `Devel::MOD` when `-d:MOD` is used. When you used `the debugger` you mean *the interactive debugging*, but I mean *Perl's debugging functionality*.

Comment: Or to use the terms from the docs, there is the Perl debugger (`perl5db.pl`), and there is debugging support (enabled by `-d`). The OP asked how to detect if the debugger is being used, but your answer shows how to detect debugging support. My original comment stands.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are useful for what I was doing.  I'll put it on my Perl cheat sheet.

```
if ( $INC{ "perl5db.pl" } ) {
   say "Debugger is running";
}

if ( $^P ) {
   say "Perl is in debug support mode";
}
```